# Registration flow using FB.login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want to change Login + registration flow with FB Javascript SDK using FB.login().

Now FBML way wroks fine:

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="<?php echo $config["base_url"]; ?>test.php" size="small"></fb:login-button>
```

on clicking the button above the following code triggers the div to show registration plugin

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // show registration form   
           document.getElementById('reg').style.display = "block";
          }
         });     

// registration form placed in a div 
<div style="display:none;width:540px;position:relative;margin:0 auto;" id="reg">     
<fb:registration fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
redirect uri="http://app.sunosunaao.com/test.php" width="530">
</fb:registration>
</div>
```

But Is there a way to show the above div once user logged in from FB.login()? Because If I use FB.login(), it directly goes to Facebook Permission page, and once connected the condition in the following function is

```
response.status === 'connected'

hence the registration plugin is not triggered 

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // show registration form   
           document.getElementById('reg').style.display = "block";
          }
         });
```

Any Idea as to how i can subtitute

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="<?php echo $config["base_url"]; ?>test.php" size="small"></fb:login-button> with FB.login();
```

Comment: I need an answer to this as well. The only thing we can pass into FB.login is a callback and a permission, so this seems to not be possible, but I need it to be in order to get my site to work on mobile web.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach events in your javascript code like what was described in this post here 
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // this code is executed after login success
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      // this code is executed after logout success 
    });
```

I hope that will help.