# When I use the facebook javascript SDK for authentication it fails on mobile phones and ipad

Tags: facebook, authentication, mobile

Javascript authentication works great on browsers but once I use the website on mobile, I always get this error on the login popup.

Sorry, the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration. Please download the newest version of the application.

Instead of showing the usual login popup, it goes to m.facebook.com and it produces this error. Whats interesting is clicking on the spanish link, makes it work again.

--EDIT--

After doing some research and tinkering, ive nailed it down to this:

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="http://www.example.com/page#register" onlogin="authenticate.facebookLoginCallBack()"></fb:login-button>
```

Its possible the pound sign blows it up. I need the pound sign because i dont want to redirect off the page,instead i want to trigger a js registration popup.

My guess is that the # gets into the redirect-url, and then must somehow get transformed again on its way to getting redirect to m.facebook.com and that makes it fail there.

--EDIT--

I thought about redoing the flow by creating my own button and calling FB.login, but there is no way to tell the API to stop at login, and load my own registration. The problem is summed up here [Registration flow using FB.login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474816/registration-flow-using-fb-login)

Realistically it seems we are only provided with one option here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/
Login + Registration Flows

and it doesnt work in my situtation

---

VISUALS

Typically the user clicks on this button

[image: login button]

Then they see this dialog. (Notice it says www.facebook.com in the url)

[image]

But they see this dialog on mobile. (This is loading from m.facebook.com)

[image: redirect dialog]